# Mostrar un dato como value de un input a través de AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

Intentaré ser lo más clara posible.

1.- Muestro las fotos que tengo guardadas en mi BBDD. Cuando clickeo sobre una se abre una ventana modal que muestra la foto sobre la que he pulsado e información de la misma, información *QUE RECOJO TAMBIÉN DESDE LA BBDD*.

```
<?php
  $instruccion2= "SELECT * FROM producto";
  $consulta2=mysqli_query($conexion, $instruccion2) or die("No pudo realizarse la consulta2"); 
  echo '<form action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" role="form">';
  while($filas2=mysqli_fetch_array($consulta2)){
      $nombreDirectorio="img/";
      echo "<img class='estilo2' alt='logo' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#ventanaModal' src='".$nombreDirectorio.$filas2[4]."' onClick='verVentana(event)'>";
  }
?>
```

2.- Usando AJAX recojo la `src` de la imagen que pulsé.

```
<script>
function verVentana(event){
//Recojo la ruta de la imagen
var imagen=event.target.src;

//hago un split para sacar el nombre de la imagen de la ruta entera
var imagen = imagen.split("/");
imagen=imagen[imagen.length-1];

//envío el nombre de la imagen a través de AJAX a la ventana modal
var dataString= 'imagen=' + imagen;
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "val_medios.php", //url desde dónde espero una respuesta
    data: dataString,
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {
        $("#tituloModal").val(data);
    },
    error: function () {}  //PONER LOS ERRORES

});
</script>
```

3.- El código de abajo es la página desde dónde espero la respuesta. Como podéis ver aquí estoy sacando la información de la bbdd de la imagen en cuestión. El tema es que lo que quiero es que esa información aparezca como `value` de un `<input>` en el formulario. Debe de ser sencillo pero no se me ocurre como hacerlo. En el código anterior, dónde implemento la función AJAX, he puesto ésto: `$("#tituloModal").val(data);`
pero no funciona.

```
<?php
//Incluyo la conexion
include 'includes/conexion.php';

//Creo la variable
$imagen=$_POST['imagen'];

if(!empty($imagen)){
        $instruccion1="SELECT * FROM producto WHERE imagen='".$imagen."'"; 
        $consulta1=mysqli_query($conexion, $instruccion1) or die("No pudo realizarse la consulta");
        $fila=mysqli_fetch_row($consulta1);
        $mensaje=$fila[2];

        echo $mensaje;
    }
?>
```

`<input>` de mi ventana modal dónde quiero que aparezca la info:

```
<input type="text"  name="tituloModal" id="tituloModal" value=''>
```

Comment: Podrían ser varias cosas, primero deberías realizar un echo de $fila[2] o del arreglo completo con var_dump($fila) para ver que valor imprime y verificar que la consulta te esta devolviendo un valor

Comment: Lo primero gracias por responder. Sí, lo está devolviendo

Comment: ¿Devuelve una cadena o un arreglo? si estas segura de que tiene valor en php puedes hacer un console.log a data en el sucess del ajax, para ver que estas recibiendo: success: function (data) { console.log(data);
        $("#tituloModal").val(data);
    },

Comment: Curiosamente, si en vez de:  $("#tituloModal").val(data);                        pongo: $('#mensaje').html(data);  y lo envío a <span id="mensaje"></span>   sí que aparece la información

Comment: Si es modal, [debes hacer algo parecido a esto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16227063/5587982) para que funcione. O sea, situar el `input` en el elemento modal, que es donde está realmente.

Comment: ¿El `id` con valor `tituloModal` es único en el documento HTML o existen varios? La búsqueda por `id` puede fallar estrepitosamente si existen varios porque se usa `getElementById` y sólo se modifica el valor del primero, no de todos ellos. En ese caso deberías cambiar `#tituloModal` por `.tituloModal` para que busque por clase y cambie todos ellos o bien diferenciar los `id`s de todos los elementos.

Answer (score 1):

Si en `data` ya obtienes el valor que deseas, sólo debes setear dicho valor de esta forma:

```
$("#tituloModal").attr('value', modal);
```

Indicas que quieres setear al atributo `value`, el valor de la variable modal.